# Visitor's nodes not suitable to be replaced by visitor?

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

In my small compiler I currently have a hand-made AST.

I was considering the idea of having a visitor that would look after nodes of a certain type `X` and would replace them by nodes of type `X'`. The trouble is that it seems that it isn't something easy to implement with the visitor pattern.

The only way I can see to make this work would be to have visit() methods to all kinds of nodes that could possibility have a node of type `X` as child and put my node replacing logic there, but there may be lots of those nodes. Plus, if I later decide to add a new kind of node, I incur the risk of not remembering to check for that new special case in this visitor.

### What's the problem I'm trying to solve:

For the current case I have in my tree nodes of type `FunctionCall` that convey only the name of a operation as well as its parameters.

I'd like to substitute those with a `MethodInvocation`, with the appropriate OOish transformation:

```
m(A, B) -> A.m(B)
m(n(A, B), C) -> (A.n(B)).m(C)
```

Of course this can be done in a thousand of different ways, being the easiest one to simply try to consider only a `Call` class in which there may or may not exist a target, but I'd like to be as explicit as possible (that is, using different kinds of nodes), to express different things, if possible.

Comment: Why do not type checking control put on Node itself ? I mean call Visit() on ALL nodes, but only nodes with type X, will do what you want. After, if you will add a new type Y -> Y', it will have Visit() method too, and take care of the transformation of itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. Could you explain a little more? But from what I understood, I wouldn't want to have to call visit() on all my 1000 types of nodes!

Comment: I mean, with Visitor or not, you nead traverse, by the way, all tree you have. The thing you want to avoid is calling Visit() on EVERY node, but you need by the way call something, like NeedVisit(), IsTypeINeed()..., whatever. So you can just have a method bool NeedVisit(), which will return FALSE on all types except X. In case of TRUE result of that method call Visit().

Comment: If I got you correctly, the problem is that you are assuming that I may only want to replace one kind of node. In fact, I may want to replace any kind of node, leading to a need to make one such method for all the possible nodes my system would have.

Comment: I agree with Tigran, if I may expand it a bit more, a NeedVisit or I would say a `bool AcceptVisitor<TVisitorType>()` would be more appropriate, that way you could base your accept logic on the visitor type that is attempting to visit your node.

Comment: I solved the problem a couple of days ago. Later I'll post the solution.